# Filter and match TYPEFORM array answers ID to question ID PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is the answer array

```
  array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["field"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(12) "U350qj1OagCK"
      ["ref"]=>
      string(36) "ec451735-c848-49a0-9ea1-4641301c0941"
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "email"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "email"
    ["email"]=>
    string(26) "example@gmail.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["field"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(12) "S0gpV5SAUUyV"
      ["ref"]=>
      string(36) "c671be6e-7356-4c42-9a0f-a4e716640443"
      ["type"]=>
      string(10) "short_text"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "text"
    ["text"]=>
    string(4) "James"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["field"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(12) "gBi6qCaJqFvC"
      ["ref"]=>
      string(36) "db33dc10-468d-45e4-b1e4-5e2bd1a69407"
      ["type"]=>
      string(10) "short_text"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "text"
    ["text"]=>
    string(7) "Dow"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["field"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(12) "MUGfdZvP7NYu"
      ["ref"]=>
      string(36) "f10d0d80-d824-4c6f-a291-9567f74ab25d"
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "yes_no"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "boolean"
    ["boolean"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["field"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(12) "kmljt9kFVgIc"
      ["ref"]=>
      string(36) "4717a18c-5d1f-4043-9c19-d24d174d4e05"
      ["type"]=>
      string(15) "multiple_choice"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "choices"
    ["choices"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["ids"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(12) "m6V1pl0Kbqz6"
      }
      ["labels"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "None of the Above"
      }
    }
  }
}


$array2['firstname'=>"S0gpV5SAUUyV", 'email'=>"U350qj1OagCK"]
```

There are 3 arrays or key inside the main answer array(field, type, and the key holding the actual answer), I need a PHP function to filter the ID in the field array to return each answer using another  array (array2) which contain all ID and change the key of the actual answer key to the key of array 2

What I expected to get

```
$finalarray["firstname"=>"Dow", lastname=>"James"];
```

Comment: Please always present your array data in an instantly usable format (such as `var_export()` text) so that your data is instantly ready for contributor processing.  Attractively formatted data increases the probability of asking a clear question that people will actually want to answer.  Is one array meant to serve as a lookup for the other array? I don't know.  I don't follow the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your statement, but maybe my code can help you.

I don't know where you get "lastname" key ($finalarray).

```
<?php

//$answers and $array2 are your input arrays. Desire result is in $array2.

$fields = array_column($answers, 'field');
$ids = array_column($fields, 'id');

$texts = array_column($answers, 'text');

foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
    $idIndex = array_search($value , $ids);
    $array2[$key] = $texts[$idIndex];
}

?>
```

Result:

```
$array2 = array('firstname' => 'Calisto', 'email' => 'Eric');
```